# WebView and mailto link

Tags: android, android-webview

Problem resolved, I forgot to add this line:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I havew a WebView with a email link.

Here is my HTML email link:

```
 href="javascript:location.href='mailto:'+String.fromCharCode(97,110,105,109,97,108,115,64,109,100,112,105,46,99,111,109)+'?'">animals@mdpi.com</a>.</p>
```

I am trying to catch when the user clicks on this link with this code:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
        if(url.contains("mailto")){
            System.out.println("mailto");
        }
    return true;
    }                      
    });
```

But I am never entering in the if.

Comment: I think, what ur code does here is check the URl for "mailto" and not the actual content where "mailto" is present. You have to get the content and check whether it has mailto or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
        if(url.contains("mailto")){
            System.out.println("mailto");
        }
        return true;
    }                      
});
```